# How do I click an image to play and audio in html?

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio, onclick

I am making a website where you can listen to music that I make. Instead of just having a classic audio player, I want there to be a play/pause button.

When I click on the play/pause button, it should execute its corresponding task to the audio player.

Keep in mind that the audio source of the player changes depending on what song I am listening to.

I tried this but it didn't seem to work

```
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audio-player');
    var centerImage = document.getElementById('cmage');

    // Add a click event listener to the center image
    centerImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Check if the audio is paused or ended
      if (audioPlayer.paused || audioPlayer.ended) {
        // Play the audio
        audioPlayer.play();
      } else {
        // Pause the audio
        audioPlayer.pause();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe "not working"? There is some simple debugging you can do. For example: is the click listener being called correctly? What is the status of `audioplayer` at that point in the code. You should use your browser dev tools to help you.